# Reasons for incarceration in the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, legal

I'm looking for a dataset that contains the incarceration numbers in the United States broken down by reason of incarceration. E.g. 30% theft, 20% drugs, 10% gun violence, etc. Bonus point if it is broken down by year and US state.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.prisonpolicy.org/reports/pie2022.html has such stats, shown as the Mass Incarceration: The Whole Pie 2022:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Data source: https://www.prisonpolicy.org/reports/pie2022.html#datasection